# Publish on LinkedIn company page

Tags: linkedin-api

So I'm trying to publish a post on a company page using the ugcPosts API.
When I'm doing in to a personal account it works great but when I'm doing it for a company page I get status "201 Created" but it doesnt appear on the company page.

I'm using the test company page https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco/

The user I'm authenticated with has permissions:

```
- r_liteprofile
- r_emailaddress
- w_member_social
- w_organization_social
- r_organization_social
```

I make the call to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
```

with the body

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:2414183",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "A share comment"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
            "media": [
                {
                    "status": "READY",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "A description"
                    },
                    "originalUrl": "https://linkedin.com/",
                    "title": {
                        "text": "A title"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any problems with https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco/ test company page? Is there another company page used for testing?

Like I said, I recieve "Created" response but where is it then? The devtestco page doesnt have any posts at all which I find weird since I cant be the only one using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tested with a "real" company page instead and it worked, so there seems to be something weird with the page https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco/